# SELECT same data from same table just with conditions as different columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I think it is best to show you he query first:

```
    SELECT 
    Positive.Amount AS PosAmount, 
    Negative.Amount AS NegAmount, 
    booking.Correction
FROM (booking)
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ID, Amount FROM booking WHERE Amount < 0 ) 
    AS Negative ON booking.ID = Negative.ID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ID, Amount FROM booking WHERE Amount > 0 ) 
    AS Positive ON booking.ID = Positive.ID
```

What I am trying to achieve here is the following. I want the amount of each booking depending if it is positive or negative in a different column. Is that possible in another, much cheaper way? I mean joining a table to itself can not be the best way, can it?

The table looks like:

[image]

And the desired result is like this:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are the tables/schema?

Comment: I think it best if you show the data set and desired result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use a `CASE` statement here. No need for subqueries and self-joins:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount END as posAmount,
    CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount END as negAmount,
    correction
FROM booking
```

Comment: Thank! I did not know about this. Great! Speed the query up like a rocket!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you want.  Perhaps it is aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Amount > 0 THEN b.Amount ELSE 0 END) as PosAmount, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN b.Amount ELSE 0 END) as NegAmount, 
       b.Correction
FROM booking b
GROUP BY b.correction;
```

Perhaps it is just two different columns:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Amount > 0 THEN b.Amount ELSE 0 END) as PosAmount, 
       (CASE WHEN Amount < 0 THEN b.Amount ELSE 0 END) as NegAmount, 
       b.Correction
FROM booking b;
```